# Windows Phone 8/8.1 get toast events

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I would like to have my add pick up and fire a event anytime a toast message happens on the system with C#. Can anyone help me.
please

Comment: Your "add"? did you mean "app"? Anyway, I don't think that's possible.

Comment: I doubt this is possible, in as much as you app being allowed to access content and actions from other apps without explicit permission.

Comment: *any* toast message?  You don't have access to that information.  If it's a toast message you app has registered for, that is handled by a separate DLL from your "app" and you can do almost anything you need to do.  If you're more specific, someone can probably provide more specific advice.

Answer (score 1):

There is no APIs available to 3rd party developers that allows them to hook into any toasts messages from other applications than their own.

For your own application, you can hook into WNS toasts while in the foreground, or have a custom background process for handling RAW toasts (although only relevant if you're writing a VoIP app).